# Take GET-parameter from any place of application (Symfony2)

Tags: php, symfony

I'm new in Symfony, but I see that it's very good framework. Now I'm working with Yii and some moments in Symfony can't understand... Sorry)

How can I take GET-parameter from any controller (for example ?ref=), processing it parameter (save REF ID in session) and return current user for current page but without this GET-parameter?

Answer (score 2):

1. [Create an event listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html) that listens on [`kernel.request`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel/introduction.html#the-kernel-request-event) event.
2. Check if given URL contains required parameter, and handle it according to your needs.
3. Return a redirect response to the very same URL but without `ref` parameter:

   ```
   public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event) {
       if (!$event->isMasterRequest()) {
           return;
       }

       if (!$event->getRequest()->query->has('ref')) {
           return;
       }

       $ref = $event->getRequest()->query->get('ref');

       // do whatever you need

       $url = ...; // prepare redirect URL
       $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($url));
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to try this variant)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use next construction:

```
http://example?ref=123


public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $ref = $request->query->get('ref');
}
```

Comment: Oleg, thank you, but it should be universal getter for all controllers in current application.

Comment: Just a suggestion, instead of trying to apply Yii concepts to Symfony 2, just embrace the Symfony 2 way of doing things.  You really don't need universal getters even though you may be used to them.